# What is the correct way to alter timestamp values in a tablerow for MariaDB

Tags: timestamp, mariadb, data-manipulation

On a MariaDB Server Version 10.1.34-MariaDB I have a database d with table `timestamp_manipulation_experiments` and each row in t contains a field called timestamp of type timestamp(6). Values in those fields look something like '2012-04-21 10:09:20.000000'.

How can one correctly alter the field in a way that refers to the old value? Let's say one would like to de/increase the timestamp of the row with id = 2 by x minutes and y seconds or even a week.

Trying something like

```
UPDATE d.timestamp_manipulation_experiments
SET `timestamp` = `timestamp` + '0001-01-01 01:01:01' WHERE id = 2;
```

and then looking at the result

```
SELECT * FROM d.timestamp_manipulation_experiments;
```

caused some mistakes and did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Two functions from https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/date-time-functions/ 
have been pointed out to me.
Both of them work fine.

- **DATE_ADD** see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/date_add/

For Example:

```
-- add 2 Minutes and 1 Second to the current timestamp and look at the result
UPDATE d.timestamp_manipulation_experiments
SET `timestamp` = DATE_ADD(`timestamp`, INTERVAL '2:1' MINUTE_SECOND) WHERE id = 2;
SELECT * FROM d.timestamp_manipulation_experiments WHERE id = 2;
```

- **TIMESTAMPADD** see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/timestampadd/

For Example:

```
-- add 1 week to the current timestamp and look at the result
UPDATE d.timestamp_manipulation_experiments
SET `timestamp` = TIMESTAMPADD(WEEK,1,`timestamp`) WHERE id = 2;
SELECT * FROM d.timestamp_manipulation_experiments WHERE id = 2;
```